# Start Menu Error in Python 3.6.2, Pygame 1.9.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, pygame

I decided to make Pong in pygame as a nice starter project. This error is not so nice though. I got to the stage where I wanted to add a start menu with two buttons, start and quit. I made it so that when your mouse hovered over the start button and you pressed space it would fill the display with black. Then I would proceed to make the game. But when I do just that the window freezes and doesn't respond. Here is my start menu code:

```
def startMenu():
        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        gameDisplay.blit(font2.render("PONG", True, white), (250, 0))
        start = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (210, 300, 40, 40))
        quit = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (600, 300, 40, 40))
        gameDisplay.blit(font1.render("Start", True, white), (170, 350))
        gameDisplay.blit(font1.render("Quit", True, white), (560, 350))

        mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        #start button
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if mousePos[0] > 210 and mousePos[0] < 250:
                    if mousePos[1] > 300 and mousePos[1] < 340:
                        play = True
                        while play:
                            gameDisplay.fill(black)
startMenu()
```

I've also included my entire main code here:

```
import pygame, time

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 800
displayHeight = 600

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
gameCaption = pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
gameClock = pygame.time.Clock()
font1 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
font2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)

def gameLoop():

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

        def startMenu():
            gameDisplay.fill(black)
            gameDisplay.blit(font2.render("PONG", True, white), (250, 0))
            start = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (210, 300, 40, 40))
            quit = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (600, 300, 40, 40))
            gameDisplay.blit(font1.render("Start", True, white), (170, 350))
            gameDisplay.blit(font1.render("Quit", True, white), (560, 350))

            mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()



            #start button
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if mousePos[0] > 210 and mousePos[0] < 250:
                        if mousePos[1] > 300 and mousePos[1] < 340:
                            play = True
                            while play:
                                gameDisplay.fill(black)
        startMenu()

        pygame.display.update()
        gameClock.tick(60)

gameLoop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Thank you for reading and I hope you can help!

Answer (score 1):

```
while play:
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
```

That's gonna run forever, forever filling the display with black.

Comment: So is that why it was crashing?

Comment: I believe so. If you put `break` after `gameDisplay.fill(black)` the program doesn't crash. The screen goes black while you're holding the space button and goes back to the main menu when you release.

Comment: is there a way to make it stay black? I tried calling a function but I couldn't because I think I couldn't access another function inside another function.

Answer (score 0):

The window freezes because you're not processing events in the `while play:` loop, so the operating system decides that the program has become unresponsive and locks it up. You need to call at least [`pygame.event.pump()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) in the while loop to prevent the freezing or just use an event loop `for event in pygame.event.get():`.

The way you're trying to implement scenes is kind of odd. As a beginner you shouldn't try to nest functions in other functions. Rather do something similar to the following example: Create separate functions for the menu and the game with their own while and event loops and then add another function (`main`) that manages these scenes. If the user clicks on the `start` button, just return the next scene function, then in `main` you assign it to the `scene` variable and call it in the next iteration to run the current scene function.

Also, check out how I use the `pygame.Rect`s that `draw.rect` returns and their `collidepoint` method to do the collision detection with the buttons. `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events have a `pos` attribute which you can use instead of calling `pygame.mouse.get_pos`.

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
gameClock = pygame.time.Clock()
font1 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
font2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)


def startMenu():
    scene_done = False

    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    gameDisplay.blit(font2.render("PONG", True, white), (250, 0))
    start_button = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (210, 300, 40, 40))
    quit_button = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, (600, 300, 40, 40))
    gameDisplay.blit(font1.render("Start", True, white), (170, 350))
    gameDisplay.blit(font1.render("Quit", True, white), (560, 350))

    pygame.display.update()

    while not scene_done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button.
                    if start_button.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        return gameLoop
                    elif quit_button.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

        gameClock.tick(60)


def gameLoop():
    scene_done = False

    while not scene_done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return startMenu

        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        gameDisplay.blit(font1.render("Game loop", True, white), (260, 150))
        pygame.display.update()
        gameClock.tick(60)


def main():
    """This function manages the scenes.

    Call the current scene function and when it's done
    assign the returned function to `scene`."""
    scene = startMenu

    while True:
        scene = scene()

main()
```

Comment: When you're more familiar with classes/object oriented programming, you should better use [a finite state machine like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3kghhj/simple_state_machine_example/) to implement scenes instead of functions.